# Do female believers get rewarded for their monthly menses?

Tags: women, hadith-interpretation, menses

> 'A'isha reported Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) as saying:
>
> A believer does not receive (the trouble) of running a thorn or more
> than that but Allah elevates him in rank or effaces his sins because
> of that.
>
> [Sahih Muslim 2572 b](https://www.sunnah.com/muslim/45/60)

Can the same ruling be applied to the monthly pain that many Muslimahs go through on a monthly basis?

I understand they tend to loose out some sawaab as they are excused from the Fard prayers during this time. But is it made up implicitly through other ways?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer is : Yes.

One hadith used as an evidence for that is:

> Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) entered upon me at Sarif while I was weeping (because I was afraid that I would not be able to perform the ,Hajj). He said, "What is wrong with you? Have you got your period?" I replied, "Yes." He said, "This is a matter Allah has decreed for all the daughters of Adam, so perform the ceremonies of the Hajj as the pilgrims do, but do not perform the Tawaf around the Ka`ba." Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) slaughtered some cows as sacrifices on behalf of his wives. ([Sahih al-Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/73/15))

Here 'Aisha felt sadness because she was not able to accomplish her duty of tawaf at hajj with the prophet (), but he () informed her that this is a matter that was decreed by Allah and she should make the best of it by performing all other permissible duties.
And Allah says:

> Does He who created not know, while He is the Subtle, the Acquainted? ([67:14](https://legacy.quran.com/67/14))

So Allah knows that a woman might not be able to perform some of her worships or duties in such a stage, so if HE somehow left her suffering or made her responsible for that that would be unjust and that's not acceptable! SO there's no reason for a woman to worry for that.

Another hadith shows under certain circumstances we may not perform a duty but would even be rewarded as if we did it:

> 'When a slave falls ill or travels, then he will get reward similar to that he gets for good deeds practiced at home when in good health." ([Sahih al-Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/56/205))

So a woman is not stopping her daily worship (in first place nafl or optional) because of her own will, but following Allahs orders so he might reward her during these days as if she performed them, as long as she was used to do so or had the intention to do so (see also the [known hadith](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/1/1) about the importance of intention).
Imam ibn Hajar said in his fath al-Bari (see [here](http://www.islamweb.net/newlibrary/display_book.php?flag=1&bk_no=52&ID=5450) in Arabic) that this hadith applies to any person that used to perform a good deed and was hindered from doing it as  was clearly mentiond by abu Dawod in his version of the hadith (see [here](https://sunnah.com/abudawud/21/3)): "what was accustomed to do when he was well and staying at home will be recorded for him"

And as menses is often accompanied by pain etc. the hadith you've quoted might also apply. As they would get the rewards for their patience and acceptance of what happened according to scholars.